# Is there an easy way to create duplicate variables in SAS?

Tags: sas

Suppose I have a dataset:

```
Product DMA Home_sales
A       1      5
A       2      12
A       3      13
B       1      5
B       2      12
B       3      13
```

Is there a easy way/short cut to get to a data set where you have variables by product:

```
Product DMA Home_sales_A  Home_sales_B 
A       1      5              0
A       2      12             0
A       3      13             0
B       1      0              5
B       2      0              12
B       3      0              13
```

I have 100 variables that need this type of transformation by product, so is the only course of action to write multiple if statements or is there a more efficient way?

Comment: If you're moving them over like that, why do you still have the first column? Is it really necessary or redundant at this point in time?

Comment: @Reeza I would need the first column as I am running a linear regression where that column is my interaction variable

Comment: So you're trying to create categorical indicator data. You don't need to do that. That's why you usually add it to the CLASS statement and SAS will do that automatically. Otherwise, GLMSELECT will often create the data. It will give you binary variables that you can them multiply out with your DMA variable using an array so that it's relatively simple. I don't have time to code that but I can point you to some examples on how to create the binary indicators. The array portion should be relatively simple.

Comment: https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Communities-Library/How-to-create-dummy-variables-Categorical-Variables/ta-p/308484 There's my write up as well as links to some SAS blogs that discuss the binary variable portion.

Comment: @Reeza basically I'm running a pooled model, and instead of having one  home sales variable with a fixed interaction by product, and I am running a model with two different home sales variable which should be equivalent. I know I can easily run a fixed interaction but there are certain constraints in my software where I need to create two different variables

Comment: Well, the method outline above is relatively straighforward. You may also be able to do a PROC TRANSPOSE and merge it back with your original data. Then set anything missing to zero. The complexity of either is about the same in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

You could try doing this all through SQL with a macro:

```
    DATA have;
    INPUT Product $ DMA Home_sales;
    CARDS;
A       1      5
A       2      12
A       3      13
B       1      5
B       2      12
B       3      13
;

%macro transform_product();
    PROC SQL noprint;
        * get product names ;
        SELECT distinct Product into :products SEPARATED BY " " FROM have;

        * create columns for sales using case ;
        CREATE TABLE want as SELECT *
        %do i=1 %to %SYSFUNC(countw(&products.));
            %LET prod=%SYSFUNC(scan(&products.,&i.," "));
            ,CASE WHEN Product="&prod." then Home_sales else 0 end as Home_Sales_&prod.
        %end;
        FROM have;
    QUIT;
%mend transform_product;

%transform_product();
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way, but again you need to know the number of groups ahead of time. This calculates that and then uses it in the next step.

```
data have;
input Product $ DMA Home_sales;
cards;
A       1      5
A       2      12
A       3      13
B       1      5
B       2      12
B       3      13
;;;

proc sql noprint;
select count(distinct product) into :num_groups from have;
quit;

%put &num_groups;

data want;
set have;
array homes(&num_groups.) ;
by product;
retain index 0;

if first.product then index+1;


*set remaining to zero;
do i=1 to dim(homes);
if i ne index then homes(i) = 0;
else homes(i) = home_sales;
end;

drop index i;
run;
```